# How do i make an image scale when ever I reload a page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Using https://sassiholford.com/ as a case study, each time this page load the banner image scale in, how do I achieve this effect ?

Comment: Please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi you must use **animation** in css.
this is simple Example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <style>
    
    .img-animation{
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;align-items: center;
      min-width:90vw;
      min-height:90vh;
      position: absolute;
      animation: image .8s ease-in;
    }
    .img-animation img{
      max-width: 100%;
      max-height: 100%;
 
    }

    @keyframes image {
      0%{
        transform: scale(1.2);
      }
      100%{
        transform: scale(1);
      }
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="img-animation">
    <img src="https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/sassiholford/wp-content/uploads/2021/02/Untitled-design-2021-02-25T085721.320-2560x1440.png" alt="any">
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please how do I achieve this scroll effect on this page https://sassiholford.com/shop/separates/dunster-shorts/

Comment: can use something like this:   @keyframes image {
      0%{
        bottom: -2rem;
      }
      100%{
        bottom: 2rem;
      }
    }

Comment: I don't understand, referring to the stick div and scrolling div image

Comment: thats handle with javascript and libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Container with adjustable image...

Note how I set the **width**, **height**, and **size** of the image via CSS.

This will make it scalable regardless of screen resolution.

```
.ContainerWithImage {

 position:absolute; 

 left: 10px; top: 20px; 

 width: calc(100% - 20px); 

 height: calc(100% - 300px);

 background-image: url("C:/abc/flowers.jpg");   /* <-- set your path to an image */

 background-position: 0% 0%;

 background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

The HTML...

```
<div class="ContainerWithImage"></div>
```

Standalone program...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>

<style type="text/css">

.ContainerWithImage {

 position:absolute; 

 left: 10px; top: 20px; 

 width: calc(100% - 20px); 

 height: calc(100% - 300px);

 background-image: url("C:/abc/Media.png"); /* set your image */

 background-position: 0% 0%;

 background-size: 100% 100%;
}

</style>

</head>

<body>

<div class="ContainerWithImage"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Works at my end... so I don't know what you're doing there.